# Merging of Two space objects into single space

Tags: c#, .net, list, merge

Here, Space is a class with (xposition, yposition, zposition, length, depth, height) as its elements and there is a list of type space.

I need to check with in the list whether it follows some conditions which are in if condition.

If it satisfies, then I merge the two spaces into single space. After that, I remove both the spaces which I have used. It actually means merging of two spaces into single space.

The new List is created. Again I treat it as new list and do the same procedure until it does not satisfies the conditions.

My problem is, it is going into infinite loop. I want to resolve this.

```
public class MergeSpace
{
    public List<Space> Mergespace(List<Space> Listofspaces)
    {
        foreach (Space space1 in Listofspaces)
        {
            foreach (Space space2 in Listofspaces)
            {
                //int count = 0;
                if ((space1.sheight == space2.sheight)
                    && (space1.sdepth == space2.sdepth)
                    && (space2.xposition == space1.xposition + space1.slength)
                    && (space2.yposition == space1.yposition)
                    && (space2.zposition == space1.zposition)
                    && (space1.semptyspace == true)
                    && (space2.semptyspace == true))
                {
                    Space space = new Space();
                    space.xposition = space1.xposition;
                    space.yposition = space1.yposition;
                    space.zposition = space1.zposition;
                    space1.slength = space1.slength + space2.slength;
                    space.sheight = space1.sheight;
                    space.sdepth = space1.sdepth;
                    space.semptyspace = true;
                    Listofspaces.Add(space);
                    Listofspaces.Remove(space1);
                    Listofspaces.Remove(space2);
                    Mergespace(Listofspaces);
                }
```

Comment: Listofspaces.Remove(space1); this will definitly throws error because u are trying to remove an item from list while the list is in use

Comment: Thanks for replying. can u pls suggest me how i can do it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MergeSpace
        {
            public List<Space> Mergespace(List<Space> Listofspaces)
            {
              List<Space> mergedspacelist = new List<Space>();
              int count=0;
                foreach (Space space1 in Listofspaces)
                {
                    foreach (Space space2 in Listofspaces)
                    {
                        //int count = 0;
                        if ((space1.sheight == space2.sheight)
                            && (space1.sdepth == space2.sdepth)
                            && (space2.xposition == space1.xposition + space1.slength)
                            && (space2.yposition == space1.yposition)
                            && (space2.zposition == space1.zposition)
                            && (space1.semptyspace == true)
                            && (space2.semptyspace == true))
                        {
                            Space space = new Space();
                           space.xposition = space1.xposition;
                            space.yposition = space1.yposition;
                            space.zposition = space1.zposition;
                            space1.slength = space1.slength + space2.slength;
                            space.sheight = space1.sheight;
                            space.sdepth = space1.sdepth;
                            space.semptyspace = true;
                            mergedspacelist .Add(space);   
                            count++;                         

                        }
                }
          }
          if(count>0)
         {
           Mergespace(mergedspacelist );
         }
}
```

i dont know what your actual need is, i think this will avoid the infinite loop

Comment: did you found solution for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions always will satisfy for same instance of Space. The instance will merge with itself.

```
if (!space1.Equals(space2))
{
   if ((space1.sheight == space2.sheight)
   ...
}
```

Comment: No. space2.xposition == space1.xposition + space1.slength This condition will not satisfy.

Comment: if space1.slengt will be equal with 0 ?

Comment: Thanks for replying me. can i know is there any other method better than this.

Comment: I think it will be better if you check out of the foreaches if there was merging action, call your method again and if there was not don't call it again.